# Install openface on jupyter notebook in docker container

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

So I have a docker container with openface python code thanks to this guide:

https://cmusatyalab.github.io/openface/setup/

However, I'd like to create a jupyter notebook that is able to import openface as a package, and then I would play around with it. How can I do this?

Alternatively, I downloaded a docker jupyter notebook with Python 2, but I'm not sure how to install openface. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

You have to base one image to write your own dockerfile to include another. The image you need is in [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/bamos/openface), while its Dockerfile is [here](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/blob/master/Dockerfile).

From the `openface` project, could see it needs to install a lots of things, so what I suggest you is use `openface` image as base, add `jupyternotebook`, like next:

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM bamos/openface

RUN apt-get purge -y ipython && \
  pip install tornado==4.5.3 && \
  pip install jupyter notebook
```

**Execute:**

```
$ docker build -t abc:1 .
$ docker run -p 8888:8888 --name test -idt abc:1 jupyter notebook --allow-root --ip 0.0.0.0
```

Finally, open `http://your_host_ip:8888`, then you could see the webpage, you will be asked to enter token, use `docker logs test` to get the token. Then you can try to import `openface` in notebook.

Comment: thanks atline! Do you know how to add to a dockerfile for an existing image? Having trouble finding the answer online

Comment: Not sure understand you correctly. If you mean modify the existing image's dockerfile, [this link](https://github.com/cmusatyalab/openface/blob/master/Dockerfile) just is the dockerfile of openface, you could clone the whole repo, modify it, and build. But I guess this is not the common way to do that, use the base image to extend it in your own dockerfile as my answer suggest is most used way. And above answer already could make you open jupyter & import openface, anything wrong?